# ng-click in template only work once, but stop working after going back to the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-ng-click

I have a Single page app website that I want the menu tab to change class to active when the page is selected.  In my home.html template, I have an `<a>` tag link to my history page.  When this link is clicked, the history menu item should have an active class.  It works when I first load the site, but it will not work after that if user goes back and forth with the history page and home page.  Any ideas?
Note, both menu and the home content are templates I loaded in using ng-include and ui-view(via ui-router).
index page:

```
<body onresize="setWidth()" ng-app="app" ng-controller="changeTab">

<div data-role="page" >

 <!--include the menuTemplate set the current index to appropriate value-->
 <div ng-include="'templates/menuTemplate.html'"></div>

</div>
 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <div ui-view></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

menuTemplate.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="desktopNav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="topNav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li ng-click="setIndex(0)" ng-class="(index==0)? 'active':''"><a id="homeButton" ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
       <li ng-click="setIndex(1)" ng-class="(index==1)? 'active':''"><a ui-sref="history">History</a></li>
       <li ng-click="setIndex(2)" ng-class="(index==2)? 'active':''"><a ui-sref="ensembles">Ensembles</a></li>
       <li ng-click="setIndex(3)" ng-class="(index==3)? 'active':''"><a ui-sref="staffs">Staffs</a></li>
       <li ng-click="setIndex(4)" ng-class="(index==4)? 'active':''"><a ui-sref="career">Career</a></li>
       <li ng-click="setIndex(5)" ng-class="(index==5)? 'active':''"><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

home.html (VIEW) template:

```
<p><a href="history" ng-click="setIndex(1)">Learn more...</a></p>
```

Angular JS:

```
angular.module('app').controller('changeTab',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.index;

  $scope.setIndex = function(val){
    $scope.index=val;
  }

  $scope.getIndex = function(val){
    return $scope.index;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Are scope values of the parent controller getting updated ?

Answer (score 1):

`ui-sref-active` would save you the trouble of `ng-click` and `ng-class`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="desktopNav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="topNav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li ui-sref-active="active"><a id="homeButton" ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
       <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="history">History</a></li>
       <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="ensembles">Ensembles</a></li>
       <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="staffs">Staffs</a></li>
       <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="career">Career</a></li>
       <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate controllers for navigation template and page templates, other wise main controller always resetting the $scope.index value

Answer (score 0):

just try ui-sref-active from @Danial's answer, work like a charm :)

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ui.router']);
angular.module('demo')
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // default state
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        template: "<h3>This is home.</h3>"
      })
      .state('career', {
        url: "/career",
        template: "<h3>Career.</h3>"
      })
      .state('contact', {
        url: "/contact",
        template: "<h3>Contact.</h3>"
      });
  })
  .controller('MenuCtrl', ['$log',
    function($log) {

      $log.debug('MenuCtrl activated');
    }
  ]);
```

```css
.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px
}
.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MenuCtrl as menu">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="desktopNav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="topNav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="career">Career</a>
          </li>
          <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```